# Upgrade swig 2.0 or newer 

Tags: linux, fedora, software-installation

I'm using `Fedora 13` and I have `swig 1.3` installed:

```
$ swig -version
SWIG Version 1.3.40
```

I need to upgrade it to `swig 2.0`. How is this done?.

Comment: I think you should be able to upgrade the package by running `yum update swig` as root.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# yum update swig
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update

Comment: @hesse It is showing like this again unable to update

Answer (score 2):

if a more recent version is not available for Fedora 13, backporting is always an option. You should check whether more recent versions of Fedora have 2.0, as backporting existing packaging is easier. This is not always possible, depending on how complicated the build dependencies are. I do such things on Debian all the time. Judging from the Debian package build dependencies, it should not be a problem in this case. Basically, try rebuilding the source package (source rpm) on Fedora after installing the build dependencies. Note that installing the binary package (rpm) on Fedora 13 directly will probably not be an option because the runtime dependencies cannot be satisfied, but you could try it if the package management system can handle failure gracefully (I don't know if this is the case for Fedora).

Alternatively, you can probably use the packaging for 1.3 with the source 2.0 tarball. Otherwise, you can do a local install.

UPDATE: It doesn't look like `swig` is available for Fedora 13, at least from the official sources. [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=swig) is a reasonable starting point if you want to find source rpms to rebuild.